# Permutations with repeated item

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have:

1. Orange
2. Apple
3. Orange
4. Guava
5. Pineapple
6. Watermelon
7. Strawberry

Note the repeated Orange. Out of these 7, I have to choose 4 fruits. How many permutations are possible?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: *Permutations* is not the word that you want to use here (unless the order of the fruits matter). Rephrase it as *Combinations*.

Comment: But generally we can say it permutations

Answer (score 1):

Its just simply cases 1) no orange is selected ${5\choose 4}=5$ .2)when one orange is selected is $1.{5\choose 3}=10$ and 3)both oranges are selected so $1.1.{5\choose 2}$ so total ways are $5+10+10=25$

Answer (score 1):

Add up the following:

- The number of combinations containing $0$ oranges, which is $\binom54=5$
- The number of combinations containing $1$ oranges, which is $\binom53=10$
- The number of combinations containing $2$ oranges, which is $\binom52=10$

Comment: I have given the same answer ? Why again and dont see any mathematical difference

Comment: Thanks, very clear. If the order of the fruits did matter though, how would we work that out?

Comment: See selection is different and selecting $\text{and}$ arranging is different